# JavaScript class memory usage

Tags: javascript, class, v8, spidermonkey

So I've been doing some JavaScript class-like stuff such as

```
MyClass = function()
{
   var x;

   this.sayX = function()
   {
      alert(x);
   }
}
```

but I've also seen

```
MyClass = function()
{
   this.x = 0;
}

MyClass.prototype.sayX = function()
{
   alert(this.x);
}
```

The big question is, am I still wasting memory space in today's JavaScript engines, or are they capable of seeing the duplication in my method and optimizing them out? The reason I ask is because I'd rather do proper data hiding and not have to prefix absolutely everything with 'this'.

Comment: As a note, you can use [with(this) { }](http://javascript.about.com/library/blwith.htm) if it helps you out.

Comment: DO NOT use "with". It's dangerous to use and will be removed from future implementations of ECAMScript. Cannot stress this enough - it is much better to pretend that "with" does not exist in JavaScript.

Comment: If you do it the first way, if you do any inheritance you'll need to be a lot more careful about what you do, how you mix the two techniques, when you call the super constructor, etc.

Answer (score 5):

The memory footprint of the first one will always be  larger. Consider `prototype` as a shared package of methods that all instances can use. It is effective because you don't create a new function for every instance, but you're reusing the existing method already in memory.

The good news is that the two ways you showed can be combined.

```
MyClass = function () {
   var x;
   // public method with access 
   // to private variables
   this.sayX = function () {
      alert(x);
   };
}
// method that doesn't need access to private variables
MyClass.prototype.sharedMethod = function () {
   // ...
}
```

But as far as you're dealing with small codebase, you shouldn't worry about memory usage. You can even use patterns like

```
// everything will be created for every
// instance, but the whole thing is nicely
// wrapped into one 'factory' function
myClass = function () {
   // private variables
   var x;

   // private methods
   function doSomethingWithX() {}

   // public interface
   return {
     sayX: function () {
       alert(x);
     },
     publicMethod: function () { .. },
     // ...
   };
};
```

*Note, I intentionally changed myClass to lowercase, because it's no longer a constructor function and there's no need to use `new` when invoking!*

---

**UPDATE** - there's a third pattern which well suits your needs:

```
MyClass = function (x, y, whatever) {
   this._init.apply(this, arguments);
}

// The prototype creates a scope for data hiding.
// It also includes a constructor function.
MyClass.prototype = (function () {
   var x; // private
   return {
     _init: function (x_in) {
       x = x_in;
     },
     sayX: function () {
       alert(x);
     },
     // ...
   };
})();
```

Comment: This is not strictly true ("The memory footprint of the first one will always be larger"). Imagine that there is only one object of said type in existence at a time. Although then you could perhaps argue the first case has another execution context bound... but that's even finer hairs :-)

Comment: Your comment is hardly constructive. If he needs only one instance of an object he creates a singleton and doesn't worry about memory footprint.

Comment: That's very informative, but it doesn't actually answer my question at all. Can modern JavaScript engines optimize out that overhead? I may just build some tests to find out.

Comment: The first sentence answers your question. The two code you showed are not identical because they have different scope chains, so **it can't be optimized**. I've updated the answer with a **third pattern**, which let's you use data hiding, uses shared function (small memory footprint), and has a constructor.   
*Demo:* http://jsbin.com/osixa4

Comment: It should be noted that the third pattern is arguably non-idiomatic as it requires the use of the `new` keyword and each instance is unique, however all instances share the same state. In some ways they're like instances, in others like singletons. Executing `five = new MyClass(5); seven = new MyClass(7); five.sayX();` yields "7".

Answer (score 0):

Revisiting this a huge amount later, but it turns out V8 is smart enough that it doesn't create multiple instanced of that function in the first method. Go hidden classes :D

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hWhMKalEicY